# Efficiently searching for custom objects in large Python lists

Tags: python, string, algorithm, dynamic-programming, lcs

I have a list of custom Python objects and need to search for the existence of specific objects within that list. My concern is the performance implications of searching large lists, especially frequently.

Here's a simplified example using a custom Person class with attributes name and age:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

people = [Person("Alice", 30), Person("Bob", 25), Person("Charlie", 35)]
```

Currently, I'm using a list comprehension and the any() function to check if a person with a specific name and age exists in the list:

```
if any(p.name == "Bob" and p.age == 25 for p in people):
    print("The person exists.")
```

Is there a more efficient way to search for the existence of specific custom objects within large Python lists?

Comment: Why don't you use sets ? Lists are very bad in finding an element, since they are not designed for this. As such, if you keep using lists, you'll always get a linear search time. On the contrary, sets are especially designed to retrieve an element in `O(1)` operation. This implies creating a hash function for your class though.

Comment: Can you create a set of `p.name` and search it if you just need a yes/no otherwise if you also need the object for the given name if it exists, I would build a dictionary with keys of `p.name` and values of `Person()`

Comment: Honestly I'd throw it into a SQLite in memory database and use an ORM. A couple of indexes will speed things up, and even without indexes, searching in C is a win.

Comment: @RandomGuy If you implement \_\_hash__ don't you also need to implement \_\_eq__ ?

Answer (score 2):

if the fields you are going to be filtering on are low, then you could first create a hash set of those fields. then knowing if a person named "bob" exists is O(1) instead of O(n) in case of list iteration

Answer (score 1):

I mean technically speaking if equality checks are set up for it, you could create the `Person` object you're looking for and just see if it's in the list.

```
people = [Person("Alice", 30), Person("Bob", 25), Person("Charlie", 35)]

if Person("Bob", 25) in people:
    print("The person exists.")
```

This will only work if the `Person` object you use in your condition and the `Person` object in the list evaluate to the same object. So this solution may or may not work for you.

You could also stand to gain performance by using a set inistead of a list as stated in @RandomGuy's comment.

### Edit:

If you want a more appropriate search you can use a set or a dict:

```
people_set = {(p.name, p.age) for p in people}
people_dict = {(p.name, p.age): p for p in people}

if ("Bob", 25) in people_set:
    print("Exists")

bob = people_dict[("Bob", 25)]
```

Comment: This does not answer the question, which was about efficiency.

Comment: @RandomGuy This is a more efficient way I don't see how this doesn't answer the question

Comment: The performance of your solution is strictly equivalent to the solution of OP, so no it does not answer the question which is about efficiency for large lists.

Comment: @RandomGuy I edited my answer to include set and dict solutions

Answer (score 1):

One way to improve the performance of searching for specific objects within a large Python list is to use a dictionary instead of a list. This approach involves creating a dictionary where the keys are the attributes that you want to search by, and the values are the objects themselves.

Here's an example of how this approach can be applied to your Person class:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

people = [Person("Alice", 30), Person("Bob", 25), Person("Charlie", 35)]

people_dict = {}
for person in people:
    people_dict[(person.name, person.age)] = person

if ("Bob", 25) in people_dict:
    print("The person exists.")
```

Comment: It is far more practical to then directly use a set

Answer (score 0):

If we implement a couple of dunder methods in your class we can then use a set as follows:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self._name = name
        self._age = age
    def _key(self):
        return self._name, self._age
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self._key())
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, type(self)) and self._key() == other._key()

_set = {Person('Andy', age) for age in range(18, 100)}

print(Person('Andy', 55) in _set)
```

**Output:**

```
True
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `Person()` class is immutable you can use a frozen dataclass and a set:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Person:
    name: str
    age: int


people = {Person("Alice", 30), Person("Bob", 25), Person("Charlie", 35), Person("Mary", 47)}
```

```
print(people)
>>> {Person(name='Bob', age=25), Person(name='Charlie', age=35), Person(name='Alice', age=30), Person(name='Mary', age=47)}

print(f'{Person("Bob", 25) in people=}')
>>> Person("Bob", 25) in people=True

print(f'{Person("Mary", 44) in people=}')
>>> Person("Mary", 44) in people=False
```

But you will not be able to mutate them:

```
p = people.pop()
print(p)
>>> Person(name='Mary', age=47)

p.age = "99"
dataclasses.FrozenInstanceError: cannot assign to field 'age'
```